# How to convert math/big.Int to float64?

Tags: go

I'm using Go's `big.Int` as counters in a long running service where the statistics counters might overflow a regular `uint64` over a long run. Occasionally I need to calculate something like, "what's the average rate since program beginning?", needing a division like `float64(big.Int) / time.Since(beginning).Seconds()`; the precision loss of conversion is acceptable in the rate calculation.

But this kind of `float64(big.Int)` conversion doesn't work.
I see the package has a
[`big.Int.Uint64`](https://golang.org/pkg/math/big/#Int.Uint64)
conversion method but it's undefined if the value overflows a regular `uint64`.
I wonder why the standard library doesn't provide a to `Float64()` method and is there any workaround how to get a floating point value?

Answer (score 22):

You can convert a `big.Int` to a `big.Float` using the [`Float.SetInt`](https://golang.org/pkg/math/big/#Float.SetInt) method.

```
i := big.NewInt(12345)
f := new(big.Float).SetInt(i)
```

Then you can either convert `f` as a float64 with the accepted accuracy, or use the `big.Float` methods to calculate the output with greater accuracy.

Comment: thanks; I read the doc again, just realized the `func (z *Float) SetInt(x *Int) *Float` is exactly what I need

Comment: You can also use `big.Rat` to do the division by duration you mentioned, depending on how worried you are about accuracy.